# Comparing 2 arrays, printing what's in common and flagging what isn't

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an example of my problem here. Take 2 arrays, 1 represents movies I have already downloaded and 1 represents movies yet to be download. I want to print a new array that is basically the 'movies yet to be downloaded' array but with flags that say "NOT DOWNLOADED" on the videos I haven't downloaded.

The twist is sometimes the videos are actually different but have the same name.

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ykhch9ng/

```
var websiteVidsArr = ['vid1.wmv', 'vid1.wmv', 'vid2.wmv', 'vid3.wmv', 'vid4.wmv'];
var downloadedVidsArr = ['vid1.wmv', 'vid2.wmv', 'vid3.wmv'];
var nonDownloadedVidsArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < websiteVidsArr.length; i++) {

    if (downloadedVidsArr[i] === websiteVidsArr[i]) {
      nonDownloadedVidsArr[i] = websiteVidsArr[i];
    } else {
    nonDownloadedVidsArr[i] = websiteVidsArr[i] + ' NOT DOWNLOADED';
    }
}

console.log(nonDownloadedVidsArr);
//preferred output:
//["vid1.wmv", "vid1.wmv NOT DOWNLOADED", "vid2.wmv", "vid3.wmv", "vid4.wmv NOT DOWNLOADED"]
```

Comment: What about Lodash or equivalent with [`difference`](https://lodash.com/docs/#difference) and friends?

Comment: If two different videos could have the same file name, you should consider using an unique id for your videos to identify them, because without an unique id you can't tell  that the videos are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution should work.

```
var websiteVidsArr = ['vid1.wmv', 'vid1.wmv', 'vid2.wmv', 'vid3.wmv', 'vid4.wmv'];
var downloadedVidsArr = ['vid1.wmv', 'vid2.wmv', 'vid3.wmv'];

var tempDownloadedArr = downloadedVidsArr.slice();
var nonDownloadedVidsArr = websiteVidsArr.map(function (video) {
    var downloadedIndex = tempDownloadedArr.indexOf(video);
    if (downloadedIndex === -1) {
        return video + ' NOT DOWNLOADED'
    } else {
        tempDownloadedArr.splice(downloadedIndex, 1);
        return video;
    }
})

console.log(nonDownloadedVidsArr)
```

Comment: Hi @shawon191, on line 4 it seems you're trying to copy `downloadedVidsArr` to `tempDownloadedArr`. If this is the case you would need to replace the line with something like (from lodash) `var tempDownloadedArr = _.clone(downloadedVidsArr);` because you're just making a reference which means that changes to `tempDownloadedArr` will actually be changes to `downloadedVidsArr`. You can see this for yourself by logging those two variables and seeing they're both empty at the end of the code.

Comment: I like the `slice()` approach. Haven't seen it before. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I'm really curious, what is the `slice()` for in `var tempDownloadedArr = downloadedVidsArr.slice();` I mean does the slice method really prevent mutating `downloadedVidsArr`? How?

Comment: @fromspace Yes the `slice()` method will copy the whole array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score -1):

As tadman pointed out you can do this w [lodash](http://www.lodash.com)

1. get the difference between the two `_.diff`, then append `NOT DOWNLOADED` `_.map`.
2. find what items `downloadedVidsArr` and `websiteVidsArr` have in common `_.intersection`.
3. put them together `_.union`

Code Below:

```
var websiteVidsArr = ['vid1.wmv', 'vid1.wmv', 'vid2.wmv', 'vid3.wmv', 'vid4.wmv'];
var downloadedVidsArr = ['vid1.wmv', 'vid2.wmv', 'vid3.wmv'];
var diff = _.chain(websiteVidsArr).difference(downloadedVidsArr).map(vid => `${vid}  NOT DOWNLOADED`).value();
var result = _.chain(websiteVidsArr).intersection(downloadedVidsArr).union(diff).value();
```